# How to have more even (normalized) sound when watching movies on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, video

I've heard that there are better solutions out there these days than this one from 2018: [Uneven sound levels on movies - partial fix I found](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=275315).

I'd like a solution that allows me to let go of the volume lever while I'm watching a movie and stop scrubbing a couple of seconds back multiple times over every time there's a dialogue due to the sound being uneven.

It may be a hardware/audio driver related too, but I only get this on the Ubuntu boot of my laptop, not on the Windows one or on my Ubuntu desktop.

What would be a modern 2023 fix to this Ubuntu movie sound issue?

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the first couple seconds of testing Pulse Effects ([the flatpak version](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects)). The app does take about 10 minutes to open, but once it's open and you turn on a filter, you immediately hear the change. Simply turning on AutoGain is enough to see an improvement.

To me it made the movie watchable. A stark difference. I won't be using it all the time probably, but it's definitely useful.